# Boot Ubuntu link from vhd in physical machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, vhd

I had installed ubuntu linux using VirtualBox into a  vhd file.
In that i have created gpt partition table and first partition was root partition and no boot partition.
Now I want to boot my physical machine that is my laptop from that vhd file which contains linux.
I referred this link but vhdfuse package has been removed and is not available now.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309900/deploy-linux-into-and-boot-from-vhd

Comment: Please answer i am in need